# Save Progress between two scenes in Unity (2D Platformer)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm still struggling to figure out how to code this in Unity. I have a button (which is it will change to scene 1 to scene 2, vice versa) then in scene 1 I walk towards the middle of the level already, but if I press the button it will change to scene 2 then my player resets into the start of the level, I want it to be in the middle of the level in scene 2, I want it somehow save my progress in scene 1 and will input into the scene 2. Because my concept is I have a level in scene 1 that my player cannot pass through an obstacle, then if i press the button (which is the scene change) ill design a level into scene 2 that there's no obstacle into it, and the player can pass through.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class that contains static member variables and store the information in there.

```
public static class SceneData {

    public static int Value1;

    public static string Value2;
}
```

Then in Scene1 you could store them, like so:

```
SceneData.Value1 = 8;
SceneData.Value2 = "test string";
```

Then in Scene2 you could access them, like so:

```
var mySceneDataValue1 = SceneData.Value1;
var mySceneDataValue2 = SceneData.Value2;
```

Alternatively, you could use the same type of concept I have proposed but instead making use of `PlayerPrefs`, find more information in the Unity documentation about that [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Or a third approach I can think of would be to save the values to local storage in one scene and access that local storage in another scene. An example of this can be found on the Unity forums [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1300019/how-do-you-save-write-and-load-from-a-file.html).

Hope this helps.